# read xml file by linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

i have xml file like Below and `Device` class and i want get `List<Device>` from my xml file
how i can do that by linq

```
            XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(SharedData.CONFIGURATION_FULL_PATH);
            var q = loaded.Descendants("device").Select(c => c);
```

but of course this code Does not work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
<device>
  <username>aa</username>
  <AgentName>aa</AgentName>
  <password>aa</password>
  <domain>aa</domain>
</device>
<device>
  <username>bb</username>
  <AgentName>bb</AgentName>
  <password>bb</password>
  <domain>bb</domain>
</device>
<device>
  <username>cc</username>
  <AgentName>cc</AgentName>
  <password>cc</password>
  <domain>cc</domain>
</device>

</settings>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Device> devices = new List<Device>(loaded.Descendants("Device")
                                             .Select(e =>
                                               new Device(e.Element("username").Value,
                                                          e.Element("AgentName").Value,
                                                          e.Element("password").Value,
                                                          e.Element("domain").Value
                                                         )));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var devices =
    loaded
        .Descendants("Device")
        .Select(e => new Device(
            e.Element("username").Value,
            e.Element("AgentName").Value,
            e.Element("password").Value,
            e.Element("domain").Value))
        .ToList();
```